# Python regex for exact match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to check if my input has a length of {5,50} for any kind of characters.
I used this code:

```
re.match('.{5,50}', my_string)
```

the problem is that when there are strings with more than 50 characters it doesn't return None. What should I do?

Comment: `re.match('^.{5,50}$', my_string)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this specific case, there's no need to use regex. Instead

```
5 <= len(my_string) <= 50
```

is sufficient. If you insist on using regex, make sure to include `^` for the beginning and `$` for the end of the string:

```
re.match(r'^.{5,50}$', my_string)
```

`^` is optional here, since `re.match` - in contrast to `re.search` - always starts matching at the start of the string.

Answer (score 3):

If your user input can be something other than ASCII, such as `u'เมื่อแรกเริ่ม'` then the user perceived length of the string (9 Thai characters) can be quite different that the string length in bytes (13 bytes because of combining characters.)

```
>>> s=u'เมื่อแรกเริ่ม'    # 9 graphems
>>> len(s)
13
```

There is no instant, easy solution to this in Python since support for integration over a string by [grapheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) is lacking.

The easiest is to use the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) that has more extensive unicode support than Python's `re` module. Then you can get the length of a string by graphemes:

```
>>> regex.findall(r'\X', s)
['เ', 'มื่', 'อ', 'แ', 'ร', 'ก', 'เ', 'ริ่', 'ม']
>>> len(regex.findall(r'\X', text))
9
```